# Detecting end of string without using functions

Tags: php, string

How to find out end of PHP string? I have one task: recognize string length without any functions. I know all strings in PHP ends with null byte (`\0`), but I can't know elements of string after last symbol.

For example, this will not work:

```
while($a[++$length]);
```

How to know length of string without using any functions?

Comment: That null byte is an implementation detail. I don't think you have access to the null byte at the end. PHP isn't C. Could be wrong' but I don't think your approach will work.

Comment: @evilone I doubt any sane educator would introduce students to programming with *php* of all languages.

Comment: So the best way in your opinion is causing `Uninitialized string offset` notices?

Comment: It is not homework. I am beginner web developer. I have some expirience with programming on ASP.NET and earning PHP now.  I try solve some tasks from one php site, and it is a part of one task.

Comment: Please prove your statement: "all strings in PHP ends with null byte ("\0")". `$string = 'abc'; $string[1] = '';`

Comment: Why can't you just do `strlen($string)`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use functions (like `strlen`)?  They will be more efficient than any other method.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this limit was in the task. What is this task I commented above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In php, strings **do not** end with a null byte. For example, `$s = 'a';echo $s[1];` produces a warning (that's why you shouldn't test with `$a[$length] == ""`). Also, php strings can contain null bytes - they're really byte arrays.

However, you can use the language construct [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to test whether reading the value of `$a[$length]` would produce a warning:

```
$a = "a\0b\0c";
for ($length = 0;isset($a[$length]);$length++) ;
echo $length; // 5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = 'hello';
$length = 0;
while (isset($string[$length])) {
    $length++;
}
echo $length; //5
```

Comment: It is not working, if I have digit 0 in the string. It should be like $length = 0;
while ($string[$length] !="") {
    $length++;
}

Comment: This has nothing to do with a `NUL`-byte. `isset($string[42])` would have the same semantics. (As document in [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), NUL is not NULL.)