# Determine string length without built in functions

Tags: php

Well, this works but I was hoping someone could show me how to improve it. It seems that there is a cleaner way to do this:

```
function beanCounter($bean)
{
    $counter = 0;
    $i = 0;
    while($bean[$i] != '') {
        if($bean[$i] != ' ') {
        $counter++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $counter;
}

// following test case returns 26
$testString = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
$stringLength = beanCounter($testString);
echo($stringLength);
```

I'm thinking if I use a regex I could actually count ONLY characters and be able to account for apostrophes or periods in multi-sentence strings. Obviously there are built in functions that can do this but I'm not interested in them

Thanks!

Comment: You're not seriously asking for a cleaner way when you reject the use of strlen() or other builtin functions, do you? Also, your question does ask for the same as what your code computes. Further, you write about "account for apostrophes or periods" but without further clarifying your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And even cleaner:

```
while(ctype_alpha($bean[$i++])) {
}
```

Comment: "ctype_alpha" is a built in function

Comment: so ... this is duplicated question : [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997445/detecting-end-of-string-without-using-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use . This will conside every element seperated by space as new character and store it in a array and use `sizeof($arr)` to count the value.

`$arr[] = explode(" ",$teststring);`

Comment: This is a bit too "built in", but I appreciate the response! If I had 4 more points I'd definitely +1 you for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

```
 while($bean[$i] != '') {
        if(ctype_alpha($bean[$i])) {
        $counter++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Use ctype_alpha — Check for alphabetic character(s)

Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are alphabetic. In the standard C locale letters are just [A-Za-z] and ctype_alpha() is equivalent to (ctype_upper($text) || ctype_lower($text)) if $text is just a single character, but other languages have letters that are considered neither upper nor lower case.

> [see php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of these functions, they seem obscure enough to not count as "built in", +1.